# Installer and Directory structure

Tags: installation, directory

I'm searching the internet for some days now but can't find info on where exactly the installer makes the file and folder directory structure and writes them on the disk. I know it complies with F.S.H. policy but i want to research the code and see how is this thing working and how it knows where to install what.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu live-CD uses a custom interface ([`ubiquity`](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Ubiquity)), but underneath that (or directly, if you use the alternate/server CD) is [`debian-installer`](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller) ("d-i") from the [Debian](http://debian.org) project, on which Ubuntu is based.

The live-CD provides a full running linux environment (and the alternate install a minimal live environment) in memory. From this the new, empty drive is mounted and a minimal system copied into it. You can look through the `d-i` code to find the scripts which perform each part of the process (you might also want to look into the `debootstrap` tool).